# "She's like a cockroach what turned into a butterfly."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dialects, relative-pronouns

This is a line from *[Pocketful of Miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocketful_of_Miracles)* (1961)

> She's like a cockroach what turned into a butterfly.

Apparently in "standard English grammar" this should be

> She's like a cockroach that/which/who turned into a butterfly.

Presumably this usage of "what" in place of "that" is dialectal. What kind of dialect has this grammar phenomenon? What is this grammar phenomenon called in linguistics? I recall seeing [a comment by MetaEd hinting at this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107073/use-of-what-vs-that#comment218178_107077), but they didn't specify. The movie is an American movie and I believe MetaEd is an AmE speaker as well. [This Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162619/usage-of-what-for-that-or-than-in-bre) seems to suggest this occurs in BrE but I am also curious about its currency in AmE.

> I guess you have no acquaintances what speak dialect. – MetaEd Mar 13 '13 at 3:30

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of \*what\* for \*that\* or \*than\* in BrE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162619/usage-of-what-for-that-or-than-in-bre)

Comment: @livresque Sort of. The movie is an American movie and the comment was also from an AmE speaker I believe. I believe this also occurs in American English. Also I'd like to know the grammatical term. Maybe someone will come along and point to some passage in the CGEL.

Comment: I think the grammatical term is "an error". :)